# Why is my mac stuttering / lagging every 2 seconds + USBC Monitor

Tags: display, usb, mouse

I am having a weird issue. I was just connecting my new [ultrawide](https://geizhals.de/philips-p-line-346p1crh-a2238244.html) monitor and now my mouse stutters every 2 seconds for about 200ms. (Rough feeling, not measurements done). This happens regardless if I plug in the mouse in the monitors USB hub or directly into the macs USBC plug.

Interestingly it stops stuttering when I disconnect the USB-C to the monitor and feed the video signal via HDMI.

**Any idea what could cause this? I am having a macbook pro 16 inch model with the 5500m.**

#### Findings

- It does not have to do anything with the mouse, if i discconect the mouse completely, the mac touchpad stutters too.
- Stuttering happens also on the macbook 16 screen with the monitor connected via USBc
- Not just the mouse and moving windows are stuttering, also websites like [testufo](https://www.testufo.com/framerates#count=3&background=stars&pps=960)
- sometimes it just ends stuttering after some time of usage
- when changing the monitor resolution there is a timewindow of approx 20seconds where it does not stutter, then the stuttering begins again

#### Video

Here is a video of this happening:
https://streamable.com/zdr1pr

Comment: Does other things stutter as well, or only the mouse pointer? (i.e. for example videos playing)  Is the mouse connected via USB-C or USB-A? - Is the mouse wireless using a USB dongle, or is it completely wired?

Comment: well, in youtube i could not see it. Audio seems fine too. But testufo stutters in the same frequency (https://www.testufo.com/framerates#count=3&background=stars&pps=960)

Comment: mouse is connected via USB-A

Comment: maybe worth to mention that the trackpad also stutters when connected to that USBC monitor

Comment: ... and the mouse disconnected

Comment: Okay, so this really hasn't got anything to do with the mouse at all. Is it just a problem with this display? - or does it happen with any external display you connect?

Comment: It seems to be just with that display.. When i connect via HDMI it seems to work just fine